# Problem with dynamic controls and their viewstates on removal from updatepanel after parent postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, controls, viewstate

Some background-

I am developing a web application for employess to submit requests for time off work. The request page uses a user control that they enter the date/reason for the day off into. The user can dynamically add a new one to the page for each day off want, these are all added to an updatepanel.

*Edit* figured out whats going on, just not sure how to fix it.

Ok so the problem I am having is when a user goes back in to edit their request and deletes on of the sub requests

==========                               ==========

Request 1                                      Request 1

==========                               ==========

Request 2                      ==>          Request 3

==========                               ==========

Request 3

==========

The request 2 control is removed fine from the updatepanel via async request with no problem and shows up correctly, the problem i have is when the parent page is submitted and the controls are recreated.

==========

Request 1

==========

Old stale data instead of request 3

==========

instead of showing request 1 & 3 i am getting request 1 along with stale data from request 2 that i no longer need.

if i force the page to draw an extra control on the parent submit i see

==========

Request 1

==========

Old stale data

==========

Request 3

==========

So the data is still there just not in the place i want it to be, how do I get get rid of the stale record and get just the active requests to show up?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thx,

Justin

Answer (score 0):

Resolved issue by using ViewStateModeById